# ACPI Bios error - AE_NOT_FOUND (20181213/dswload2-160) How to solve?

Tags: linux-mint, bios, acpi

I am using a dell laptop with dual boot, Linux mint 19 and Windows 10.

It was working correctly but suddenly, between my work, it got freeze. I force restarted the laptop and it is not booting in linux at all. It it checking my disk and then return this error message. Please find the screenshot below for complete error details.

[image]

I tried rebooting it multiple times, but it comes to the same error. Windows setup is working fine though.

What does this error indicate and how can I resolve it?

Comment: No, let me try and get back @artem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue with below command.

```
fsck /dev/sda4 -y
```

[Reference](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=298632)